# How to define variables in non-technical style

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

We actually use variable definition like this in FitNesse:

```
!define variable{variable_value}
```

How could I do this with a fixture or in any other way that fits more into the convention of writing tests using **tables**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand the differences between Variables and Symbols in FitNesse and the relationship to tables.

Variables are defined so that they render before the page executes a test. The best use for variables is when you want to "hard" code a value that you are going to use frequently in a test and you know in advance. Variables also inherited by child pages, so you can set a value and reuse it.

But there is only one syntax for defining variables.

Symbols are defined at test execution time and are done within tables. You would need a method that echoes or returns whatever you are sending to it, and that will define a value at runtime that will be used whenever referenced in the test.

I've written more about this here: http://whotestedthis.squarespace.com/journal/2011/3/15/symbols-and-variables-in-fitnesse.html

See http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SymbolsInTables for more about Symbols. And http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.ImportantConcepts.MarkupVariables for more about variables.